# Subtracting Hex using 2's Complement

Tags: twos-complement

i was wondering how would i go about subtracting two hex values using 2's Complement arithmetic? I know how to convert dec to binary and hex using the 2's complement, but im having trouble understanding how to subtract. Lets say we have the example below, how would i go about solving this using 2's complement without converting to bin or dec (if possible):

```
    3A43 h - CB4A h
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all: there is no 2's compliment in any base other than binary.
I never heard of a name for the hex pendant, but since 2 is the first number which is not available in binary I would call it G's or 10's complement.
the G's complement of CB4A:

```
10000
-CB4A
_____
 34B6
```

do not forget that you can expand this number with `F`s to the left.

```
    3A43
FFFF34B6
________
FFFF6EF9
```

so the result is `FFFF6EF9` in G's complement, which can be calculated to `-9107` in sign-magnitude hex.